# How can I display the results of webform submission in a block and place it on front page?

Tags: 7, blocks, webforms, charts

So I'm using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module to collect data, and I want to display the results in a Drupal block and place it in an appropriate theme region in my site.

Like for example the following: I want to display the analysis with the charts  of my result (created with the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module) in the front page of my site.

Is that doable?

[image]

Comment: Yes I'm using Charts with (s) . 
I want to take those charts and place them in a block

Comment: Any feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 possible approaches to consider, as further explained below ...

### Approach 1: using the Charts modules

This is like rolling your own cookies. You create your chart (as you already seem to have done in the image above), using either the "[Charts API](https://www.drupal.org/node/2423431)" (= write some PHP code to populate the charts Array, whereas you put that PHP code in the content of your block) or using the "[Views integration of the Charts module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2313837)" (where you format the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) result as a block).

Disclosure: I'm a (co-)maintainer of the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

### Approach 2: using the typical Webform related charting modules

If you want to create **charts** from the survey results of the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module, there are 2 typical/popular alternatives to pick from:

- [Webform Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_charts) (used in about 350 sites), to display Webform results in a graphical manner using a charting library.
- [Webform Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_chart) (used in about 575 sites), which integrates with the "Analysis" tab of a Webform (created with the Webform module) to provide charts for each individual component's analytical data.

The Drupal 7 version of both modules, requires the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module (dependency).

### Note:

In both approaches you need to decide about which "[Charting Library](https://www.drupal.org/node/461914)" (= engine) you want to use, either Google charts (easiest setup) or Highcharts (which might require a license also). At any time it should be pretty easy to swap between either library also (that is a key feature of the Charts module also ...).

Comment: Update for the Webform related charting models: [Webform Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_charts) (used in about 320 sites) and [Webform Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_chart) (used in about 500 sites). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @herci : merci (oeps: thank you) for the stats update (I corrected my answer with them just now).